# Problem with bag file

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hii,
I wrote a bagfile . when i do rosbag info i do get the topic list but the duration is zero sec.The start and end time are same.
Here is the info listed

```
path:        record.bag
version:     2.0
**duration:    0.0s**
start:       Jan 01 1970 05:53:37.58 (1417.58)
end:         Jan 01 1970 05:53:37.58 (1417.58)
size:        3.8 GB
messages:    20883
compression: none [1887/1887 chunks]
types:       geometry_msgs/PoseStamped [d3812c3cbc69362b77dc0b19b345f8f5]
             sensor_msgs/PointCloud2   [1158d486dd51d683ce2f1be655c3c181]
topics:      /gps_pose                          7125 msgs    : geometry_msgs/PoseStamped
             /lidar_2d                          3028 msgs    : sensor_msgs/PointCloud2  
             /lidar_3d                          1886 msgs    : sensor_msgs/PointCloud2  
             /lidar_four_plane_scanner_layer1   2211 msgs    : sensor_msgs/PointCloud2  
             /lidar_four_plane_scanner_layer2   2211 msgs    : sensor_msgs/PointCloud2  
             /lidar_four_plane_scanner_layer3   2211 msgs    : sensor_msgs/PointCloud2  
             /lidar_four_plane_scanner_layer4   2211 msgs    : sensor_msgs/PointCloud2
```

I wrote the rosbag file using rosbag class . Why is this error can anyone help me out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238242/problem-with-bag-file/) by [shashank](https://answers.ros.org/users/25836/shashank/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2016-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The start and end date are both at the unix epoch, i.e. zero. You need to set the message time. It is not necessarily the same as the time in the message header, but I guess for your purpose you can copy that one, if you have no original message time.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shashank](https://answers.ros.org/users/25836/shashank/) on 2016-06-28**:
Sorry but i am confused . Is there a message time for rosbag file and a message time for topics ?? if it is so how do i set the time for rosbag file. Thanks for your replay.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-06-29**:
The messages have a timestamp in the bagfile, so rosbag knows in which sequence play them. Also rosbag uses them to publish the /clock topic, so all nodes can act as if the data were current. Some messages also contain timestamps within the payload data of the message, usually by including "Header"

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-06-29**:
How did you "write" the bagfile?